# SQL get all columns from a table along with the count of a grouped column from another table related by a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables 'projects_logs' and 'logs_attachments'. The 'logs_attachments' table is related to the 'projects_logs' by the foreign key 'project_log_id'. Every project_id is related to multiple 'project_log_id' and every 'project_log_id' is related to multiple 'log_attachment_id'. I want to get records of all the logs for a project with the count of no of attachments attached with each log.

projects_logs

```
+----------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| project_log_id | project_id |  event  |                     notes                     |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|              5 |          3 | started | Aut et dolores voluptatem id culpa inventore. | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 |
|              6 |          3 | on-hold | dolores voluptatem id culpa                   | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 |
|            241 |          3 | resumed | Isdnu sdlw o dolores voluptatem id            | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 |
+----------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

logs_attachments

```
+-------------------+----------------+---------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| log_attachment_id | project_log_id |         file_name         | file_type | attachment | file_size |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+-------------------+----------------+---------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                24 |              5 | hic                       | rtf       | 5_biY     |       1212 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 |
|                23 |              5 | omnis                     | xls       | 5_3QC     |       5594 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 |
|                26 |              6 | quo                       | xlsx      | 6_kfS     |       2765 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 |
|                27 |              6 | consequuntur              | txt       | 6_BGd     |         94 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 | 2018-10-05 07:10:47 |
|              1201 |            241 | SampleJPGImage_50kbmb.jpg | jpeg      | 241_xYP   |      51085 | 2018-10-09 12:34:19 | 2018-10-09 12:34:19 |
+-------------------+----------------+---------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

What I want

```
+----------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
| project_log_id | project_id | events  |                     notes                     |     created_at      |     updated_at      | count(logs_attachments.project_log_id) |
+----------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
|              5 |          3 | started | Aut et dolores voluptatem id culpa inventore. | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 |                                      2 |
|              6 |          3 | on-hold | dolores voluptatem id culpa                   | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 |                                      2 |
|            241 |          3 | resumed | Isdnu sdlw o dolores voluptatem id            | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 | 2018-10-05 07:10:46 |                                      1 |
+----------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple join should work here:

```
SELECT
    p.project_log_id,
    p.project_id,
    p.event,
    p.notes,
    p.created_at,
    p.updated_at
    COALESCE(a.count, 0) AS count
FROM projects_logs p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT project_log_id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM logs_attachments a
    GROUP BY project_log_id
) a
    ON p.project_log_id = a.project_log_id;
```

Comment: +1 Just wondering why would it really matter whether `project_log_id` is PK/Unique or not. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Because according to strict ANSI rules, we cannot select any columns which either do not appear in `GROUP BY` _or_ which are not functionally dependent on the columns in the `GROUP BY`.  So, if for a given `project_log_id`, there could be _two_ records with _different_ values of say `notes`, then the query I wrote makes no sense.  Now, it still might actually _run_ on MySQL, but it is bad practice.  So, if we `GROUP BY` a primary key in one table, we may always select all columns from that table.  True in MySQL, Postgres, but I think Oracle and SQL Server still do not allow this.

Comment: It's giving me error 'p.project_id' isn't in Group By.  Yes you are right project_log_id is the primary key

Comment: @Tintin Then you'll have to use a subquery, for a slightly uglier overall query.

Answer (score 1):

use join and `count()` with sub query

```
select t1.*,
COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0)  as count_logs_attachments.project_log_id
from 
projects_logs as t1
left join 
(
select project_log_id,count(*) as cnt from  logs_attachments
group by project_log_id
) t2 on 
t1.project_log_id=t2.project_log_id
```

`COALESCE` function will help to you to get 0 where no logs_attachments exist

Comment: Thanks! The sub query method is working. Can't up vote your answer, don't have the reputation needed.

Comment: There is a typo in the last line. It should be t1.project_log_id=t2.project_log_id

Comment: I'm sorry. But the accepted answer is better, choosing the right answer as accepted will help anyone who is looking for the similar solution, so I picked it up as the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer handles the situation where there are no attachments for a log. In that case it returns 0 instead of NULL. "COALESCE(a.count, 0)"

Comment: I can see that you have modified the answer to handle that situation but it was not there when I accepted the answer. It's nothing personal. I'm just trying to help the community by accepting the best answer.

Comment: @Tintin according to sample that handing is not required but from your comment it sees that you need that , btw community read your question and they will dont think you need left join here cause both tables has all id and you didn't mentioned any where in your question you need 0 where project_log_id id will no exist in 2nd table .. so it is absurd logic that you helped community. please pardon i mistaken aswered your question ,its so bothering to me

Answer (score 0):

You could write sql query like

```
select pl.project_log_id, pl.project_id, pl.event, pl.notes, pl.created_at, pl.updated_at, pla.attachment_count
from projects_logs as pl
inner join
    (select count(log_attachment_id) as attachment_count, project_log_id
     from  logs_attachments group by project_log_id) as pla
     on pla.project_log_id = pl.project_log_id
```